# Redirecting My App To My Website

Tags: facebook

I've made an app today on Facebook, but I have 1 problem, I get an SSL error when my website was framed in the canvas, so my only option is to redirect people to my website.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

I want the process to go like this:

1. Click on app
2. Accept permissions
3. Redirects to my website

The main thing here is the permissions, I require my visitors Facebook permissions before they're allowed to access my website.

Comment: _"so my only option is to redirect people to my website"_ - not, that's not an option, for two reasons: 1. Your redirect will not even happen, because you have no page that could be loaded via HTTPS into the iframe to trigger a redirect, and 2. [Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) do not allow this: _"The primary purpose of your Canvas or Page Tab app on Facebook must not be to simply redirect users out of the Facebook experience and onto an external site."_ _Getting_ a valid SSL certificate for your app, _that's_ your only option.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

add your domain in app domain field  & Website with Facebook Login  here

https://developers.facebook.com/apps//summary

then try this url for not installed  app visitors

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id= 

 appid&redirect_uri=MY WEBSITE URL&scope=WHAT EXTRA PERMISSION U NEED
```

Comment: What exactly is the cliet ID?

Comment: how do I get the client ID?

Comment: its your app_id check here
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
click on you app name copy App ID/API Key

Comment: thanks man. how do I list in the scopes (permissions) in the url?

Comment: what permissions you want ?

Comment: ahh, it redirects me to my domain, + my application token.
This is where it leads me after I allow the app.
Open pastebin, iv uploaded it there.
http://pastebin.com/fXvfu8XM

What can I do now?

Comment: well this is redirecting you to right place whats wrong ? dont want ?code=something ? you can right a code to remove it (redirect users where you want if there is code) but i think you may need it specially if your not using facebook sdk

Comment: yeah I don't want the extra code. Where exactly would I write the code? Would I need to script the app myself?

Comment: write something like this in your app (if your a php programmer)

`<?php 
if(!empty($_GET['code'])){
echo '
<script> top.location.href="URL WITHOUT CODE" </script>
';}`

Comment: you can do it full in javascript 
google how to get current page url via javascript * after getting it use this code
`<script> top.location.href="URL WITHOUT CODE" </script>`
but why you want to remove code ? y u want users to install your app ? installed user without access token is nothing

Comment: I want people to grant permission to my app. After they do that, I want to send them to my website, http://mywebsite.com.

I want the people's access token, that's why I want them to use my app to access my website.

Comment: oh I see, then how will I be able to get their access token + send them to my website?

Comment: r u using facebook javascript sdk ? whats your website programming language

Comment: I'm not using any programming at the moment. I haven't started coding the interior of the app. I'm just trying to find the easiest way for me to achieve what I want.
I have not learnt a programming language yet, that's why I'm finding it difficult to code what is on my mind.

I was hoping to get the access token + redirect people to my site with basic configration.